# make schengen visa outside your origin country/homeland

Tags: visas, schengen, tourist-visas, romania, indonesian-citizens

hello i want to ask question about schengen visa, and i'm from Indonesia. My problem is i have plan to go flight to Romania on June for an exchange program purpose, and the romania visa is being processed now. But also i want to go to Schengen Area(germany, france, netherlands) but my concern is that i might not make time for applying schengen visa in my country before my departure time to Romania. So my question is can i make the schengen visa outside of my origin country/homeland(indonesia) especially while i'm in Romania?

FYI my first choice of schengen country is Germany
Thank you..

Comment: In general, no, you cannot unless there are exceptional circumstances.  But whether you can apply in this case depends on how long you will be in Romania and on when you plan to go the Schengen area.  How long will you be in Romania?  When do you plan to go to the Schengen area?

Comment: about a month, i will be staying in romania (from 28 june - 31 july), and i'm planning go to the schengen area on 1st august

Answer (score 1):

In general, you are supposed to apply in the country where you reside (not necessarily your country of origin or homeland).  A one-month visit to Romania does not make Romania your country of residence, so you cannot apply there.

This is controlled by Article 6 of the [Schengen Visa Code](http://eur-lex.europa.eu/legal-content/EN/TXT/?uri=CELEX:02009R0810-20160412).  The article does allow for exceptions:

> Article 6
>
> Consular territorial competence
>
> 1. An application shall be examined and decided on by the consulate of the competent Member State in whose jurisdiction the applicant legally resides.
> 2. A consulate of the competent Member State shall examine and decide on an application lodged by a third-country national legally present but not residing in its jurisdiction, if the applicant has provided justification for lodging the application at that consulate.

Unfortunately for you, the visa processing handbook (available, for example, at https://www.udiregelverk.no/en/documents/schengen/16202010/) makes it clear that the "justification" must be some circumstance that prevents you from applying for the visa in your country of residence during the three months before you plan to travel to the Schengen area.  If you have a good reason to explain why you were unable to apply for a Schengen visa in March, April, or May, then the a Schengen consulate in Romania might accept your application.

Comment: ah i see, is there any chance i will get schengen visa maybe at the border of the first entry?

Comment: also i want to add some question, how can i go to zurich with only romania visa in my hand? because i already bought the plane ticket and my return ticket to Indonesia is from zurich...

Comment: @Kyan The chance that you can get a Schengen visa at the border is essentially zero.  There are some very limited circumstances in which it is supposed to be possible, namely for crew members of commercial vessels and for immediate family of EU citizens who are traveling with or joining the EU-citizen relative.

Comment: @Kyan you can transfer between external (non-Schengen) flights in a Schengen airport without a visa, because Indonesian citizens do not require a visa to do that.  You will not be able to pass through passport controls, though.